# git : Can't recover latest commit after a stash

Tags: git

I was on branch "master" and I was in the middle of editing code.  I needed to go back to an older commit to double check something, so I stashed my changes and did a `git checkout A` to get commit "A".  Now I was ready to go back to my code and start editing again.  I should have at this point done a `git checkout master` but I made a mistake and did `git stash apply`.  Not surprisingly, git wouldn't apply the stash.  But now I'm stuck.  I do a `git checkout master` and it tells me that I have two source files needing merging.  How can I get back to my latest commit, and then apply the stash so I'm ready to edit again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all your commits that haven't been garbage-collected by using

`git reflog`

At that point you can check out the commit you want, or `cherry-pick` it on to your current branch.

If git won't let you check the commit out, you may need to reset your HEAD with `git reset --hard` before checking out the commit from the reflog.  Keep in mind that you will lose any pending edits.

If none of this works for you, maybe you can save yourself using the local history in your IDE.

Comment: I had to do the reset, but after that it worked great.  Thank you!  Stackoverflow won't let me hit the accept button yet.  But I intend to as soon as I can.  Remind me if I don't get around to it.

Comment: :whew:  that's a bad feeling, huh?  Glad it worked.  With git, if you made a commit, you can probably get it back :)